# In a Biblatex SourceMap, is there a way to do a \step for many fields?

Tags: biblatex

I coded a Sourcemap performing regex substition in author field.

```
\DeclareStyleSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{%
    \map{%
      \step[fieldsource=author,%
        match={\regexp{...}}, replace={\regexp{...}}]
 ...
```

I would like to have other name fields such as editor processed in exactly the same fashion.

Of course, I could copy/paste the match/replace step used for author.

But the regex expression is rather long and complex. So I wonder if there is a way to tell the sourcemap to apply a given step to many fields ? The code would then be much more shorter and elegant.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can't do that but you could probably assign `\regexp{}`s to a TeX macro and re-use them?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Ill'do this !

Comment: @PLK I just remembered that Biber's nosort specification has aliases such as `type_name` and `type_title`. Maybe that is something that could be used in normal source maps as well (to my untrained eye it seems the structure is already in place)?

Comment: That would actually be quite hard to implement because the logic in sourcemaps is so complex. In biblatex 3.4/biber 2.5 (on SF), there is a generalised datafield set system which replaces the hard-coded nosort types. Users can now defined arbitrary sets of datafields and use them in styles, documents. They will also be passed to biber for future use. That is how the nosort `type_*` things are now implemented. I will look into integrating these sets into various parts of biber/biblatex as needed.

Comment: Actually, I realised it is quite easy to implement due to the new `foreach` mapping option, see answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `biber` 2.5 and `biblatex` 3.4 dev versions on Sourceforge;
the `foreach` option of a sourcemap can now take an explicit CSV list, the name of another field containing a CSV list or the name of a custom datafield set defined with the new `\DeclareDatafieldSet`. So, your use case is simply something like this:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite, foreach={author,editor}]{
      \step[fieldsource=\regexp{$MAPLOOP},
            match=\regexp{bigre},
            replace={replacement}]
    }
  }
}
```